# The button is not visible

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

I have a UWP application, I have added a button but when I debug the application, I can't see the button. If I add a texblock or textBox I can see them, but not the button.

I have set IsEnabled to true and visibility to visible but I am not able to solve the problem.

Also I have tried to click in the place where it should be the button but nothing happens.

This happens when I debug in local machine and when I debug in a emulator of windows phone 10.

Thank you so much.

EDIT: the axml code

```
<Page
    x:Class="SqliteEF7UWP.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SqliteEF7UWP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Button x:Name="GetVideos" IsEnabled="True" Visibility="Visible" Background="Aquamarine" Content="Buscar Videos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,98,0,510" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="button_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Foreground="BlueViolet" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="101,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="34" Width="132"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Would you add more code, like the content you place in the button? and do you have another control that could overlap the button?

Comment: Please add the xaml code.

Comment: You have hardcoded Margin - please check if your button is not outside the grid. Also - don't use hardcoded margins, use suitable Panels and or columns/rows in grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin you set for the Button is too aggressive. The object is now "squeezed". For example set Margin to "120,98,0,**200**" (or simply "120,98") instead of "120,98,0,510" and it should be visible.

BTW using hardcoded margins to setup the user interface is probably not a good idea. Use for example the Grid with columns and rows instead of margins.

Comment: Thanks. Really I was thinking that if I is shown in the designer, it should be shown in the application, but it not always true. Thank you so much.